# Linux shell: space in condition statement

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I recently learn how to program in shell.
I can't understand why those two statement produce different output. It seems if there are no spaces, test treats `10==11` as a string and always returns true.

```
$test 10==11 && echo yes || echo no
$yes
$test 10 == 11 && echo yes || echo no
$no
```

Comment: Type `help test` to see the help page

Comment: You're absolutely right; if there are no spaces, then the `test` command does not have multiple arguments to parse; it's a single string, which evaluates to true since it is not null.

Comment: If it helps you remember to use spaces, use -eq instead of == (it's more difficult to write 10-eq11 and not say to yourself "I think I should put some spaces in there")

Answer (score 0):

```
# single string, not null so true, and result is yes
test 10==11 && echo yes || echo no

# there exist space 10 == 11 not equal string comparison so result no
test 10 == 11 && echo yes || echo no
```

[Read More Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

**Equivalents**

```
if test 10==11; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes

if test 10 == 11; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no

# or this same as above
if test 10 = 11; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

**From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html**

```
string comparison

=

    is equal to

    if [ "$a" = "$b" ]

    Caution 

    Note the whitespace framing the =.

    if [ "$a"="$b" ] is not equivalent to the above.
==

    is equal to

    if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
```

Comment: Thank you, very detailed explaination. I think I should use man more.